# Compiz effects in XFCE

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xfce, compiz

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 as well as xubuntu-desktop. When I'm logged in using unity, my compiz effects work fine, but under xfce they don't seem to work. I've installed compiz config settings manager and have verified that the effects are on but the effects aren't rendering.

Where can I look to troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Xfce *does not use* Compiz – it has its own window manager, Xfwm.

You need to run Compiz in order to see desktop effects:

```
$ compiz --replace &
```